# Retirar último número com sql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Gostaria de retirar o último número o 1 desta sequencia:

```
0495747500000049908275289000100040000000041
```

Como que eu faço em sql server?

Comment: Vai remover sempre o último caracter ou vai remover o último somente ser for `1`?

Comment: não qualquer número

Comment: O tamanho é fixo? 43 caracteres?

Comment: Retirar, extrair, obter, penso que mudariam um pouco a percepção da questão apresentada.
Mas, para o que você quer, as funções LEFT, RIGHT e SUBSTRING funcionam muito bem

Answer (score 8):

Pode combinar a função `left()` para pegar todos os caracteres iniciando a esquerda até o limite que é definido por `len()` (que retorno o tamanho da string) `-1`. Algo como:

```
select left('0495747500000049908275289000100040000000041',
len('0495747500000049908275289000100040000000041') - 1)
```

Ou

```
select left(campo, len(campo) - 1)
```

Comment: e se for uma variável? tipo @teste =

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado

Comment: @FelipeMichaeldaFonseca se alguma resposta resolveu, marque como escolhida clicando no V verdinho ao lado dos pontos

Answer (score 3):

Pode utilizar tanto o LEFT quanto o SUBSTRING.

```
DECLARE @numero VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @numero = '0495747500000049908275289000100040000000041'

SELECT LEFT(@numero, LEN(@numero) - 1) AS 'LEFT', SUBSTRING(@numero, 0, LEN(@numero)) AS 'SUBSTRING';
```

## LEFT (Transact-SQL)

> Retorna a parte da esquerda de uma cadeia de caracteres com o número
>   de caracteres especificado.

## SUBSTRING (Transact-SQL)

> Retorna parte de uma expressão de caractere, binária, de texto ou de
>   imagem no SQL Server.

## [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/32823)

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar a função `RIGHT` , ficaria assim:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAMPO, 1)
```

Caso seu campo seja um número precisa converter para varchar:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CAST(CAMPO AS VARCHAR(50)))
```

Não se esqueça de alterar o tamanho do `Varchar` para a sua necessidade.

Espero ter ajudado.